# Unable to create AVD , getting "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details"

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

While creating AVD getting error shown in screenshot

[image]

Comment: so, have you checked idea.log ?

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, in windows you will need to delete any available *.ini files available in the users folder[.android/avd]....C:\Users[UserNameDirectory].android\avd